# How to refer to the correct noun in the following case?

Tags: sentence-structure

Here is the sentence I'm mentioning:

*"The fire was occasioned by a short circuit on **electric wires** of the three-phase electric motor **on** the tank*..."

In this case, I mean electric wires were on the tank, not electric motor. So is it correct to use like the above sentence?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The whole phrasing is weird. It should be:

> The fire was caused by a short circuit of the electric wires to the three-phase electric motor on the tank..."

Comment: @Andrew - Yes, thanks. I corrected as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will rephrase it. But "occasioned" is equal to "caused", so why do you suggest to use "caused"?

Comment: English is just my second language, and in this case I learnt this word from insurance wording "loss or damage occasioned by or through or in consequence directly or indirectly of any of the following occurrences". So, can you explain me why "occasioned" is an "absolutely wrong" choice?

Comment: Here is Merian-Webster definition no use as a verb https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/occasion and here is Oxford Living Dict which has a definition as verb meaning caused https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/occasion I have never heard or used occasioned as a verb. Not sure if this is British or archaic but it is absolutely weird to me.

Comment: In Longman dictionary, it functions as a formal verb which means "cause". I guess that it might be used in academic writing, such as insurance wording where I found this word. Thanks for your useful advice.